# Design Review - Resolving IDispatcher Or Dispatcher instance

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

I am in a process of extending `ObservableCollection<T>`, which will notify collection change back to UI thread from `ViewModel` in an ideal `MVVM` scenario. To achieve this, I am thinking of resolving UI `Dispatcher` through some `IOC` and eventually use the resolved `Dispatcher` instance within my custom observable type.

Draft will look like this;

```
class SafeObservableCollection<T>: ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public SafeObservableCollection(IDispatcher currentDispatcher)//maybe an instance of Dispatcher
    {
     //assign resolved dispatcher to a private member
    }
}
```

*Assumption:*  *(a) WPF application which uses one Dispatcher/UIThread. (b) I am not thinking of any deviation (APM/EPM using BackgroundWorker) apart from overriding base class members of ObservableCollection*

**Question**: 
Can you propose anything better to resolve Dispatcher instance while following the outlined code? Can you help me to nail down any possible design flaw? Such as memory leak, deadlock or anything which I overlooked.
What should be / would be the lifetime of my Dispatcher instance if I decided to go with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.5, you shouldn't invent new vehicle and use already existing functionality that can do it.

```
//Creates the lock object somewhere
private static object _lock = new object();

...

//Enable the cross acces to this collection elsewhere
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_persons, _lock);
```

and now you can acces _persons observable from any thread.

There is also WPFExtensions that has thread-safe observable; http://wpfextensions.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, here we are talking about the thread affinity issue and not synchronization issue. Can you extend on it ?

Comment: what do you mean by affinity issue? It's already solved in WPF 4.5, if you use the code I gave. Meaning UI can bind against collections that are created&managed on a seperate thread. No Dispatcher involved.

Comment: Can please refer me any link, which describe or talks about "addressed thread affinity issue" by Microsoft. Meantime, I have got the idea on how I can implement thread safe observable from the given link on WPFExtension Lib. Before accepting as answer, can you edit your original post with 'only reference to extension' since this is more close to what I wanted. Presumably, this will helps other to get the point without further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're wanting to do this to make it unit testable (since the `IDispatcher` could be mocked).  If not, then you may as well just use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` to invoke back to the main thread.

Injecting an `IDispatcher`, which resolves to a concrete that wraps the `Application.Current.Dispatcher`, shouldn't have any issues with memory leaks, deadlocks or the like, and would easily be testable/mockable.

I would recommend just leaving a reference to the `IDispatcher` in your `SafeObservableCollection` class, and not just use it to get a direct reference to the UI thread `Dispatcher` itself since you'll lose the benefits of mockability.  Just have the `IDispatcher` expose the `Dispatcher` functions you need.

The lifetime is your choice - one instance of a dumb `Dispatcher` wrapper per `SafeObservableCollection` should be fine, but if you're extra paranoid, you can have your IoC resolve it as a singleton without any issue.

Comment: @Gleltema, Thanks for your support. It's not about unit testing at least at this stage rather trying to create an application framework collection (observable collection), which can automatically propagate collection change back to UI (marshaling changes back to UIThread.) from View Model.

Comment: In that case, as noted, you could just use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` in this, unless you're wanting to avoid referencing WindowsBase.dll.  In that case, doing the full wrapper interface and injecting it will do the trick.  Even if you don't want/need testability/no-WindowsBase-reference, your setup is still fine, as long as you implement it as I described, or something similar.

Comment: Feel free to ask more detailed questions if anything I wrote doesn't make sense, or you want more clarification.